# How to set a DIV width accordion to image size

Tags: php, html, background, size

I need to set a DIV width (the height is fixed) according to the width of the image I will going to use as a background. Obviously the image is bigger than the DIV.

Let me try to explain:

HTML

```
<DIV class="book"></DIV>
```

CSS

```
.book {
  height:180px;
  background: url("hh1.jpg");
  width: ???
}
```

Now the background image "hh1.jpg" is definitely larger that the DIV. I could use the "cover" property, but  I would like to set dynamically (via php) the width of the DIV so that it will always show the whole background image.

So let's say that I have a fixed height of 180px and use a  1000(w)x1800(h) image, the resulting div should be something like 100(w)x180(h)px. If I use a 1200(w)x3600(h)px the div should be 60(w)x180(h)px and so on.

Comment: But why with PHP? Can't you do it with JavaScript?

Comment: Well, I'm trying to create a short code for WP, and prefer to do a simple math in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You could go for min-width that is always enough.
Use position absolute within a relative positioned container, so that the element will not disturb the flow of the document.

```
<div class="cont"><div class="bg"></div></div>
.cont{position:relative;}.bg(position:absolute; background: ....)
```